# How to hide variable values in url in php(When variable passed on link click)?

Tags: php

How to hide variable values in url in php(When variable passed on link click)?
i dont want to show variable values in url .please tell me some solution.

```
<td><a href="editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="deleteuser.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
```

url -:   `/showuser_list.php?msg=Record deleted successfully`

Comment: Use AJAX with POST method. Or form with POST method and buttons instead of anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onclick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href=editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that

```
<?php
echo "
<form method=\"post\" action=\"mypage.php\">
<button name=\"Abutton1\" value=\"".$row['id']." \">button</button>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks,when i ask some one he said using form will not work but i will try this.

Comment: and in your php code you can access it by $_POST['Abutton1']